# Not Able To Read Uploaded File

Tags: php, excel, filesystems

I have a problem when reading file that was uploaded

```
$fileElementName = 'file_to_import';
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file_to_import']['name']));
$filename = (rand(1000, 9999) . time()) . "." . $ext;
$save_to = "upload/" . $filename;
$msg .= " File Name: " . $_FILES['file_to_import']['name'] . ",";
$msg .= " File Size: " . @filesize($_FILES['file_to_import']['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_import"]["tmp_name"], $save_to);
@unlink($_FILES['file_to_import']);
require 'Excel_Reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($save_to);
```

Here `Excel_Reader.php` is a library to work with Excel file but new `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($save_to)` is not opening file and it outputs the following error

**The filename 45061340615478.xls is not readable**

Comment: doe move_uploaded_file work at all? Any error message from that (make sure you have errors turned on to display)

Comment: Stop overusing `@`. If `unlink($_FILES['file_to_import'])` throws an error, that's because it doesn't make sense to begin with and should be removed.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file using Excel "manually"?  It could be that the file is genuinely corrupt, or the wrong Excel version.